# Как программно свернуть приложение в Android?

Tags: android-studio, java

Здравствуйте!

Изучаю Android, пишу код в AndroidStudio. Решил сделать приложение, которое умеет сворачиваться при нажатии на кнопку "Back", или как там ее) В сети ответа на такой банальный вопрос не нашел, тут этого тоже никто не спрашивал. Возможно ли программно свернуть приложение?

Заранее благодарен за ответы)

Comment: Т.е. сворачивать по кнопке back аналогично кнопке home? Но зачем?

Comment: В целях обучения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно придумывать "сворачивания" приложения. Нет такого. Как только Ваше приложение ушло на задний фон, система его может прибить в любой момент.

Если нужно, чтобы по кнопке назад приложение "завершалось" - просто сделайте так, чтобы стек активити был пуст. Система сделает все за Вас сама.

Answer (score 4):

```
      public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
      }
```

такой код должен помочь. вставьте этот метод в класс вашей активности.